# Solving an overdetermined system of coupled ODE in a heat transfer context

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, physics

I am currently working on a mathematical model to simulate the transient behaviour of a steam generator in a nuclear reactor, but I have stumbled across some issues when it comes to solving the governing equations.

My model is based on the so called [Moving Boundary Models
for Dynamic Simulations of Two-Phase Flows](https://lup.lub.lu.se/search/ws/files/5652028/625686.pdf) in which conservation of mass and energy equations are formulated for the primary fluid in the three different flow regions; sub-cooled liquid, two-phase flow and super-heated liquid. Added to these equations are also equations describing heat transfer in the wall separating the steam and the secondary fluid, as well as conservation of energy equations for the secondary fluid.

I end up with a set of 12 equations, 9 dependent variables and 1 independent variable (time). I will not write the complete system, but as an example, a small part of my system looks like this (conservation eqs. for super-heated region):

\begin{align}
&\alpha(T_3)\frac{dL_1}{dt}+\beta(T_3)\frac{dL_2}{dt}+L_3\gamma(T_3)\frac{dh_{out}}{dt}=0\\
& \delta(T_3)h_{out}\left(\frac{dL_1}{dt}+\frac{dL_2}{dt}\right)+\epsilon(T_3)h_{out}L_3\frac{dh_{out}}{dt}=\\
&\dot{m}(h_g-h_{out})+HTC(T_3)L_3\zeta\cdot(T_{3, wall}-T_3)
\end{align}

Where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta,\epsilon$ are dependent on the average temperature $T_3$ in the region (calculated from the average enthaply $h_{avg} = 0.5(h_g+h_{out})$), $L_3$ is the length of the super-heated region and it is calculated as $L_3 = L_{tot}-L_1-L_2$, where $L_{tot}$ is the total heat exchanging length and $L_1$, $L_2$ are the sub-cooled and two-phase lengths respectively. $h_{out}$ is outlet enthalpy and $HTC(T_3)$ is the convective heat transfer coefficient which in turn is calculated from its own set of equations based on the temperature $T_3$.

To summarise, we have in this small example the dependent variables $L_1,L_2,h_{out}$ and their time derivatives written in a coupled system.

With the twelve equations I can formulate a matrix equation on the following form:

\begin{equation}
[A]_{12x9}\cdot[x]_{9x1}=[b]_{12x1}
\end{equation}
where the vector $[x]_{9x1}$ contains all derivatives as

$$[x]=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{dL_1}{dt}\\ \frac{dL_2}{dt}\\ \frac{dh_{out}}{dt}\\\vdots\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

and the matrix $[A]$ and vector $[b]$ contains constants and dependent variables.

Now that my problem has been introduced let me briefly talk about the approach I've used thus far.

My approach has been to write a RK4 solver, in later iterations it was changed into a RKF45 solver, and to recalculate all of the variables which depends on the system state eg. $\alpha(T_3)$ or $HTC(T_3)$, based on the system state in the previous iteration. However all RK/RKF solvers I've seen thus far requires the system to be on the form

$$\dot{\vec{y}}=A\vec{y}.$$

However, that's not how my system looks. My idea was then to use a least squares algorithm to solve for the derivative vector in my matrix equation and then use that as a basis for the RKF45 solver. I do suspect that this method is incorrect. I've been searching all around the internet for a potential solution to a similar problem, but almost everything assumes that the searched for time derivatives are all placed on one side of the equal sign, and that the dependent variables are multiplied with a matrix A.

**My Question:** What I would like to know is if anyone has some experience of solving a problem of this sort, and to confirm if my method involving least squares is incorrect. I would be happy to be pointed in the right direction if it is obvious where I'm doing something wrong. Also if anyone is aware of some good literature in this topic I would deeply appreciate it.

I hope that this long post makes sense, and that someone has the time/ will to guide me in the right direction.

Comment: The actual underlying physical system seems like it should not be overdetermined. Unfortunately we'd probably need to inspect the entire system to see why this happened. It is not necessarily the case that you will be able to write everything in the nice form $x'=f(t,x)$, though. Sometimes you are stuck with an implicit system where you need to do some iterations in order to, e.g., stay on some constraint manifold. Still if the problem is well-posed and there is no effect of e.g. noisy data in the constants, then least squares shouldn't really be needed.

Comment: Could you explain what "based on the system state in the previous iteration" in view of the stages of RK4 and even more RKF45? What does "previous" refer to? And if you had only access to a single state, at a single time, how many components would you need to put into the state to compute all components of the equations? I would expect that you get a DAE system $F(x,y,\dot x)=0$, where you have do identify 3 non-differentiated state components $y$, and possibly also 3 equations containing no derivatives.

Comment: @Ian Thank you for your comment. The reason here that the system is overdetermined is because I removed its dependency on pressure $p$, and on mass flow rate in the intersection between the the regions, $\dot{m_{12}}$ and $\dot{m_{23}}$. The reason for this being that those variables behaved very strange when included. I reasoned that as an approximation the pressure remains constant, and that given constant mass flow rates for inlet and outlet, the two aforementioned should be constant due to conservation of mass.

Comment: @Dr.LutzLehmann My apologies for the unclear sentence. What I mean is that I know the state of my system at  $t = t_0$ and then run one iteration of the solver to obtain the state at $t=t_0+\Delta t$. Based on this information I can recalculate all other parameters required in the solution, such as the heat transfer coefficients. Does this make it clearer for you what I meant?

Comment: So you made an approximation by just setting three of the *a priori* unknown derivatives equal to specified values? Then in principle least squares is appropriate, since you're effectively projecting onto the subspace where these additional equations hold. But the strange behavior when those equations are included points to something else wrong in your original setup.

Comment: @Ian Yes I did, apologies for not making it clear in the OP. I might have to go over the equations one more time then, but in principle, if I add the three variables back into my system and obtain a $12x12$ matrix, I should be allowed to invert it to have the derivatives on the form $\dot{x} = f(t,x)$ and then use some ODE solver? Or are you aware of a neater way to do it?

Comment: You enter the **index theory** of differential-algebraic (systems of) equations. If you can solve $F(x,y,\dot x)=0$ as $\dot x=f(x,y)$, $0=g(x,y)$ or the last one explicit as $y=h(x)$, then you can directly solve it. If that is not possible, then you need to add derivatives of the equations until you can solve for some assignment of variables and derivative orders so that in the solution no terms of higher order in each variable remain. Mechanical systems with constrains such as the pendulum in Cartesian coordinates have index 3, that is, require 2 differentiations of some of the equations.

Comment: @Dr.LutzLehmann DAEs was something that popped up from time to time when I researched different methods of solving my problem. I will look into that theory and study how to apply it to my problem. You seem really knowledgeable in the subject, are you aware of any good literature where I can study this deeper? Thank you for your inputs.

Comment: You have Hairer-Wanner: "Solving ODE II: Stiff & DAE", then Ascher-Petzold: "Computer methods for ODE & DAE". The papers of Pryce-Nedyalkov try to give the ubiquitous Pantelides method a theoretical framework and advance it thereby. All these can be found in the reference list of the wikipedia article. A lot of work was also done in the context of circuit design (large-scale systems with a large linear part, leading to (hierarchical) partitioning methods), which I do not that much about.